# ng-repeat puts "unsafe" in front of https urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, AngularJS puts "unsafe:" in front of https urls. I've tried settings up `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` and `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` like below:

```
app.config( ['$compileProvider', '$routeProvider', function( $compileProvider, $routeProvider ){   
     $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
     $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
]);
```

But it yields this URL no matter what I change above.

```
unsafe:https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test-bucket/58a0cfe00dea48a48633.png
```

What can I do to stop AngularJS from putting unsafe in front of my img urls...?

**EDIT**

Process I'm going through to show the images:

- Make a request to the back end to retrieve an object of data
- Within the object of data, there's a URL for the objects associated media
- I use ng-repeat on the collection of objects retrieved from the back end to display the images.

Here's a short example of what it looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in campaignData track by $index">
    <img class="img-responsive"
     ng-src="{{data.thumbnailFileKey}}"
     Accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's definitely Angular and not the browser?

Comment: @alex Yes. I've tried chrome, firefox, and internet explorer. They all produce the same results.

Comment: can you provide some examples of how you are building these URLS?

Comment: The SSL certificate is probobly not trusted on that site

Comment: @MarcusH It's Amazon's S3 service. I'd assume it'd be trusted? If not, how would I get Angular to trust the SSL certificate?

Comment: @Claies Check my edit

Comment: @JakeMiller didn't se that it was Amazon. The SSL is trusted. But it looks like its trying to do a redirect when hitting the url. Sure you got the correct endpoint?

Comment: @MarcusH Yeah. Whenever I right click on the broken image and remove "unsafe:", the image shows. Whenever I visit the link directly, it downloads it instead of simply showing it on the page. Maybe that has something to do with it? I wouldn't think so since it appears properly when the "unsafe:" tag is removed.

Comment: can you show some more code?  I'm not able to reproduce your issue;  this works fine without adding any kind of whitelist : http://plnkr.co/edit/FJsZEl9iIve5G6GPyjAq?p=preview

Comment: if I had to make a *guess*, I would say this is probably related to how your data is being parsed when received.